# Does posix_memalign catch signals?

Tags: c, memory, timer, memory-management, signals

Does posix_memalign catch signals? I am allocating memory using posix_memalign and running timer in the background, i get a "Interrupted system call exception", from posix_memalign in the logs.

Is it due to the timer signal? Or is there some other issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mat: Sorry, Mat i can't post the exact code due to confidentiality issues :( But my idea is clear i guess, from this question. I

Comment: @Mat: Please let me know if you need more clarifications.

Comment: The question in its current form is unanswerable. At least tell us what tool is showing this "interrupted system call exception", what OS and compiler/libraries you're using, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is: [Does posix_memalign catch signals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5675777/does-posix-memalign-catch-signals)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you're treating the return value of `posix_memalign` incorrectly. This function does not return a pointer. It returns 0 on success and an error code on failure. Perhaps you're finding `EINTR` in `errno` after `posix_memalign` returns; this is meaningless since `posix_memalign` does not use `errno`.